# What is happening when db.<collectionname>.? is called?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm new to mongodb and I want to know what is happening when `db.sampleCollection.?` is called ??

When I tried this I gets the following three dots on the terminal.

```
> db.sampleCollection.?
... 
... 
>
```

Whats that three dots mean ??

Comment: What exactly you want to do with this query?

Comment: I don't know the purpose of the query but I want to know what it is !! @titi23

Comment: From where you are trying to use it? I never saw any such query. 
 `...` means query is not valid/ there is some syntax error.

Comment: I'm getting this when using in MongoDB shell command. If the query is not valid it should have shown an error message. @titi23

Comment: You did not give answer of, `Why you are using this command?` . This way we can't help you.

Comment: I don't have any usage of this command. When I'm trying what are all the command it accepts, I came across this one. That's why I raised a question. There should be any usage of this command. Just want to explore it. Nothing more than that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply, on mongo shell you can write multi-lines and you if write something and you not close it and press enter on the shell , it will show "..." that mean your operation not closed.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/mongo/#multi-line-operations-in-the-mongo-shell

When you press "db.xcollection." the shell can see that you not complete you statement and waiting you to complete it.